# Why will PayPal Smart buttons not recognise my items array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, paypal

I have integrated the PayPal smart buttons into my JavaScript shopping cart. I am trying to allow PayPal to tell the user the items they had in the cart at checkout. For example; [image]

I know that to do this I need to use the following code:

```js
<script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                return actions.order.create({
                    "purchase_units": [{
                        "description": "Stuff",
                        "amount": {
                            "value": "20.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "breakdown": {
                                "item_total": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "20.00"
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "unit_amount": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "10.00"
                                },
                                "quantity": "1",
                                "name": "Item 1",
                            },
                            {
                                "unit_amount": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "10.00"
                                },
                                "quantity": "1",
                                "name": "Item 2",
                            },
                        ],
                    }
                    ]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                    window.location.href = "orderConfirmed.php"
                    clearCart()
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
```

In this example, there are 2 items in the dropdown tab: Item 1 and Item 2 but I need these to represent what the user has in their cart. I got an answer on her than said I needed to create amn array that held the cart item name, price and quantity.

I came up with this code, what I am trying to do is for every item in the cart, I want to return the product name, product price and product quantity. I came up with the code below:

```js
function arrayOfItems() {

        cart.forEach((cartItem, index) => {
            let currency = cartItem.price;
            let quantity = cartItem.quantity;
            let itemName = cartItem.name;

            let items = [{"unit_amount": {"currency_code": "USD","value": currency},"quantity": quantity,"name": itemName,}];

            return items;

        });

    }
```

But when I run the new PayPal script like so:

```js
<script src="cart.js"></script>

    <script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: countCartTotal()
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                arrayOfItems()
                            },
                        ],
                    }
                    ]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                    window.location.href = "orderConfirmed.php"
                    clearCart()
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
```

The PayPal buttons stop working!

### Update

After making the changes the code now looks like this:

```js
<script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                return actions.order.create({
                    "purchase_units": [{
                        "amount": {
                            "value": countCartTotal(),
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                        "breakdown": {
                            "item_total": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": countCartTotal()
                            },
                        },
                        "items": arrayOfItems()
                    }
                    ]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                    window.location.href = "orderConfirmed.php"
                    clearCart()
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
```

And is not producing any errors in my IDE, however when I run the code the JavaScript Console gives me this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be including the required breakdown. This may seem redundant, but it is required to have a breakdown section.

```
                        "breakdown": {
                            "item_total": {
                                "value": countCartTotal()
                            },
                        }
```

Also it looks like you are generating an items array, so you need to use it like so:

```
                    amount: {
                        value: countCartTotal()
                    },
                    items: arrayOfItems(),
```

All of the `currency_code` fields also seem to be required, and not optional when passing line item information, so you will need to add those back in.

That's three issues you need to fix.

If you still need help, post a runtime example of what everything is evaluating to, i.e. the output of the functions so we can tell you what's wrong

Comment: Hi Preston, thank you for all of the help with my issues, I made the changes and it still wasn't working so ran the JavaScript Console and I have updated my question to include the error it gave me! Thanks

Comment: breakdown object should be indented for clarity. then you are missing a `}` to close the amount object after it

Comment: That seemed to work and the PayPal buttons are rendering now, but it loads for a few seconds and then dissapears but i will open a new question for that as this one was ansered correctly