# PayPal Smart buttons adding items description to button

Tags: javascript, paypal

Hi I want to add a description to my smart button but my code for the items array is not working.
Please refer to this question: [Why will PayPal Smart buttons not recognise my items array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973630/why-will-paypal-smart-buttons-not-recognise-my-items-array)

I am having basically the same problem, this person's question was never resolved.
Whenever I put my function for the Items value it returns a really long error.  I am just not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
function arrayOfItems(){
   var arrayItems = []
   var items = document.querySelectorAll(".cp-info");
   items.forEach(function(item){
    // console.log(item);
    // console.log(item.children[1].children[1].children[1].textContent)
     let currency = item.children[1].children[1].children[1].textContent;
     let quantity = "1";
     //console.log(currency);
     //console.log(item.children[0].textContent);
     let name = item.children[0].textContent;

     let size = item.children[1].children[0].textContent;
     //console.log(size);

     name = name;

    //console.log(name);
    var itemInfo = {"unit_amount": {"currency_code": "USD", "value": currency},"quantity": "1", "name": name,};
    //console.log(arrayItems);

    arrayItems.push(itemInfo);
    //console.log(arrayItems);


  })

  return arrayItems;
 };
```

The array returned from the function in the console looks like this. ( the first by the 0 is just the break down

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
name: "GB Stacked"
quantity: "1"
unit_amount: {currency_code: "USD", value: "49.99"}
__proto__: Object
1: {unit_amount: {…}, quantity: "1", name: "Stacked Jeans"}
2: {unit_amount: {…}, quantity: "1", name: "GB Stacked"}
3: {unit_amount: {…}, quantity: "1", name: "Blue Stacked Leggings"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

**UPDATE TO QUESTION**

this is what I am pass in on the PayPal side

```
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                  "purchase_units": [{
                          "amount": {
                              "value": showTotals(),
                              "currency_code": "USD",
                          "breakdown": {
                              "item_total": {
                                  "currency_code": "USD",
                                  "value": showTotals(),
                              },
                          },
                          "items": arrayOfItems()
                        }
                    }],
                  });
              },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

I am not sure what I changed but it doesn't give a console error anymore and allows the purchase to happen but the order details are still empty.

JSON stringily of what I am passing in

```
  var x = arrayItems;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(x,4));
  return arrayItems;
---------------------------
this returns to the console =
[{"unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"49.99"},"quantity":"1","name":"GB Stacked"},{"unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"79.99"},"quantity":"1","name":"Stacked Jeans"},{"unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"49.99"},"quantity":"1","name":"GB Stacked"},{"unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"79.99"},"quantity":"1","name":"Stacked Jeans"}]
```

[this is a picture of the PayPal transaction screen, as you can see the order details is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSnBw.png)

Comment: Update your question with the actual JSON you are passing to actions.order.create(. Set a variable with what you are passing, then console.log(JSON.stringify(myVariable,null,4))

Answer (score 0):

We'll be able to give a more precise answer when you show exactly what you are doing in your code or passing, but it appears you purchase_units array is not valid.

It should be an array with a single (0 index) item, and that item should be a purchase_unit object with at least two keys, `amount` and `items`.

`amount` should be an object containing the required `breakdown` key with a breakdown object, and `items` should be an array of item objects

---

Code for debugging:

```
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                var req = {
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: showTotals(),
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            breakdown: {
                                item_total: {
                                    currency_code: "USD",
                                    value: showTotals()
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        items: arrayOfItems()
                    }]
                }

                console.log(JSON.stringify(req,null,4));
                return actions.order.create(req);
            },

            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }


        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Woking JSON example ([tested here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)):

[image]

```
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: 259.96,
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            breakdown: {
                                item_total: {
                                    currency_code: "USD",
                                    value: 259.96
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        items: [{"unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"49.99"},"quantity":"1","name":"GB Stacked"},
                        {"unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"79.99"},"quantity":"1","name":"Stacked Jeans"},
                        {"unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"49.99"},"quantity":"1","name":"GB Stacked"},
                        {"unit_amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"79.99"},"quantity":"1","name":"Stacked Jeans"}]
                    }]
```

Comment: I updated the question with what I am passing to the "actions.order.create(". and also "Set a variable with what you are passing, then console.log(JSON.stringify(myVariable,4))"

Comment: You'll want to debug the whole thing being passed to create. Added code above so you can see -- also forgot to pass null as second param to stringify

Comment: Like I know the literal string would work but I need the function to work because the details aren't always the same.  For the function instead of returning the variable am I actually supposed to return the JSON.stringfy?

Comment: No. It's for debugging, to see a testable string representation of your object and be able to tell what is wrong with it and hence what is wrong with the code that generates it. I posted what may be working code for you to test with your functions.

Comment: I think I found the problem I updated the question with it, please help.  I think it has to do with there not being a comma at the end of name item

Comment: You didn't update your question, you proposed an edit to this answer of mine -- but no this isn't the issue, that comma doesn't have to be there (and shouldn't be there in valid JSON, though a JavaScript interpreter will be forgiving and ignore the extra comma)

Comment: Yeah you're right. I have tried everything but I'm not sure the problem, I'm starting to think that it just doesn't accept variables.  I have put the function in directly and set the function equal to variable and then put it in and it still gives an error.  But when I console log the function and then directly copy and paste it into where it needs to be it works perfectly.  Like  everything is lined up to work it just doesn't.  It's looking impossible.

Comment: Well then unless you provide a testable example that reproduces the problem, no one can help further.

Comment: I don't think it is testable unless it's possible to send the entire file?

Comment: Create an HTML/JS snippet with the minimum code necessary to reproduce your problem. It is quite doable. Start with what is at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client and add what is necessary to it. You don't _have_ to include all your logic and HTML.